# Find a string starting from given index

Tags: rust

What is the correct way how to find a substring if I need to start not from 0?

I have this code:

```
fn SplitFile(reader: BufReader<File>) {
  for line in reader.lines() {
    let mut l = line.unwrap();
    // l contains "06:31:53.012   index0:2015-01-06 00:00:13.084
    ...
```

I need to find third `:` and parse the date behind it. Still no idea how to do it, because `find` doesn't have any param like `begin` - see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.find.

(*I know I can use regex. I have it done, but I'd like to compare the performance - whether parsing by hand might the quicker than using regex.*)

Comment: What kind of begin parameter are you thinking of? If you mean `begin` is an offset, then you'd just slice and then find `s[begin..].find(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there doesn't appear to be any trivial way of skipping several matches when searching a string. You can do it by hand though.

```
fn split_file(reader: BufReader<File>) {
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let mut l = &line.as_ref().unwrap()[..]; // get a slice
        for _ in 0..3 {
            if let Some(idx) = l.find(":") {
                l = &l[idx+1..]
            } else {
                panic!("the line didn't have enough colons"); // you probably shouldn't panic
            }
        }
        // l now contains the date
        ...
```

**Update:**

As [faiface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491989/faiface) points out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31323259/582), you can do this a bit cleaner with `splitn()`:

```
fn split_file(reader: BufReader<File>) {
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let l = line.unwrap();
        if let Some(datetime) = l.splitn(4, ':').last() {
            // datetime now contains the timestamp string
            ...
        } else {
            panic!("line doesn't contain a timestamp");
        }
    }
}
```

You should go upvote his answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Can you also tell me how performant is that? What does that `l = &l[idx+1..]` do? Does it create new slice on stack? Does it copy the appropriate bytes? I'm asking because I try to process large files and any such extra work might kill performance significantly.

Comment: Slices are references, they never represent copying nor do they represent any allocation of their own

Comment: @stej: measure, measure, measure :) In this specific case, it might well be that the bounds check `l[idx+1..]` will cost more than the the assignment itself. You can check how a slice is implemented in the [`std::raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.Slice.html) module: just an integer and pointer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot simpler solution to this problem in my opinion, and that is to use a `.splitn()` method. This method splits a string by a given pattern at most n times. For example:

```
let s = "ab:bc:cd:de:ef".to_string();
println!("{:?}", s.splitn(3, ':').collect::<Vec<_>>());
// ^ prints ["ab", "bc", "cd:de:ef"]
```

In your case, you need to split the line into 4 parts separated by `':'` and take the 4th one (indexed from 0):

```
// assuming the line is correctly formatted
let date = l.splitn(4, ':').nth(3).unwrap();
```

If you don't want to use unwrap (the line might not be correctly formatted):

```
if let Some(date) = l.splitn(4, ':').nth(3) {
    // parse the date and time
}
```

Comment: Good call. I remembered that Rust had `split()` but for some reason I didn't think of `splitn()`. BTW, it might be conceptually cleaner to use `l.splitn(4, ':').last()` instead of using `.nth(3)`.

Comment: That sounds good also. Already implemented the other solution, but I'll probably make some benchmarks including this solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just the date and not also the time, right?

```
let test: String = "06:31:53.012   index0:2015-01-06 00:00:13.084".into();

let maybe_date = test.split_whitespace()
    .skip(1)
    .next()
    .and_then(|substring| substring.split(":").skip(1).next());

assert_eq!(maybe_date, Some("2015-01-06"));
```

Comment: I assumed the time was part of the date that stej wanted to parse. Together they represent a fully-specified timestamp.

Comment: It's true, I wanted to parse the time as well. This code might look good for small files and shows another way how to solve my problem, so I upvoted as well..